# My NAS broke. How to read HDD on RAID 1 XFS to Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, nas, nfs, raid-1

My old NAS broke down. Old NAS setup was 2 x 1 TB HDD running on RAID 1. I had about 600 GB worth of content on the NAS. The broken component as far as I can tell is the enclosure not the disks. However now I'm left wondering how to access the data on one of the disks. If I try to mount it like this:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /home/oldhdd
```

I get the following error:

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'
```

I googled the error and found the following command

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md0 /dev/sdb2
```

After doing that, this worked ok:

```
mount /dev/md0 /home/oldhdd
```

Now I can access the hdd but all my data is invisible. What do I need to do to access my folder structure and data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in this, but this I would do:

Install the xfs package

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xfsprogs
sudo apt-get install xfsdump
```

and the mount your partition

```
sudo mount -t xfs /dev/md0 /home/oldhdd
```

Comment: Thanks but the filesystem turned out to be more eccentric. I had to turn to disk recovery specialist.